# How can I fit expected curve?

Tags: curves, spline

I got a few scattered points and try to fit a smooth curve, but the fitted curve is not expected.
[image]
[image]
In the first figure, the red curve is generated by the function csaps from matlab and is not smooth enough.
csaps means cubic smoothing spline from the link https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csaps.html
I fit the curve again using the corresponding points on the curve of measured points  for several times and
obtain the cyan curve. The cyan curve is still not as I expect. The second figure is what I expect. How can I get such curve?

Comment: The resulting curve depends on the function you use, i.e. polynomial of degree n, exponential function, trigonometric function, mixed function, etc.

Comment: Fit with polynomials. Start with degree 2. You’ll get a nice smooth curve that doesn’t fit your data points very well. Then successively increase the degree by 1. Each time you increase, you’ll improve the fit, but possibly introduce unwanted wiggles. Stop when the wiggles get too large.

Comment: @bubba A smooth curve without wiggles is expected. Maybe the noise in each measured   point are different and not gaussian.

Comment: @callculus42 Currently I am using cubic spline to fit the points. Using one specific function can't obtain a smooth curve without large error to measured points.

Comment: @JoggingSong. You wrote “using one specific function can't obtain a smooth curve without large error to measured points”. Sure it can. A high-degree polynomial will get you just as close as a cubic spline.